# I accidentally deleted the updates of my google play

Tags: google-play-store

I was exploring my cellphone. I came to the uninstall updates of google play. Now I can't open it nor can update my apps. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy to fix, simply make sure you have enabled "Unknown sources" in your Security section of your settings app and download and install this APK file from this reputable source:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/04/03/play-store-5-4-10-makes-the-notification-bar-transparent-on-app-pages-apk-download

It's simply a download link for the official Google Play app. When you get it installed, it should update itself automatically if there's a newer version available.